# Parent Directory Path in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, url, path

I'm trying to getting an image from a javascript file inside a "js" folder. The image is inside the "img" folder.

Root Folder: "img" folder (with "image.png" inside), "js" folder (with "javascript.js" inside), "index.html" file.

this is my code:

```
var image = '../img/image.png';
```

but it doesn't work!
If I move the javascript file in the root folder and I use `var image = 'img/image.png';` it works!
So.. how can I write the path to keep the javascript file in the js folder?
I don't want to use an http url!
Thank you!

Comment: How are you using the "image" variable? Oh, and paths need to be relative to the path of the main HTML page, not the JavaScript file.

Comment: I'm using it as icon for gmaps api 3 markers!

Comment: OK well again the path to the JavaScript file is not important - what matters is the path to the page that *uses* the JavaScript file. It's not like CSS.